Variable value changes when accessed (edebug "steps" twice on same variable)
As an aid, let me show you a video: https://streamable.com/c2bnko, though it's not needed to follow this question.
I'm going to edebug org-id-alist-to-hash (0:13 in video).  First I verify that the variable being passed in is a list (namely org-id-locations).  Which is shown true in edebug too...but then on the next edebug step, point is still on the same symbol, and now the echo area shows it as a hash table.  Which then crashes the function, of course, since it expects a list.
What could be going on?  Why would it satisfy listp, but change its mind and be a hash table before org-id-alist-to-hash can do anything with it?
I cannot make code to reproduce, since it's intermittent or depends on very particular circumstances.

I couldn't tell from the video when you started debugging, but I can see (when (listp org-id-locations) (setq org-id-locations (org-id-alist-to-hash org-id-locations))) which sounds exactly like the "started as a list, now it's a hash" symptom.  So... can you explain more clearly what the issue is?

Video is not good for StackExchange anyway since it will disappear. I think my question describes the issue adequately on its own.  But if you want to check again, you see me doing M-x edebug-defun at 0:13, and only after that do I go and eval.  The odd behavior can be observed at 0:21-0:25.

I also realize it's confusing that the thing I want to do is exactly to convert it to a hash table. :-)  The only issue is I can't, because it already becomes a hash table as it's being passed into the function that's supposed to do the conversion.

Well the video isn't there anymore.  I suggest you instead update the question with code that other people can copy/run/debug to reproduce the problem.

I cannot make such code. If I could, I'd probably solve the problem, which is intermittent... Refreshed video link, but really, the question just boils down to: why might edebug step twice on the same variable?

"which is intermittent" would be an absolutely crucial part of the question which you did not mention at any prior point.  Please update the question.  If you can't provide a test case, though, I can't help.
